# Docs with diagrams in github projects?

Tags: documentation, diagramming

I'd like to write an architecture document for a little ruby project I'm working on, and being an architecture document it'll benefit from a few box and stick diagrams.

What's the done thing on open source projects for this situation? Should I be practicing my ASCII art, or should I include PDFs or something in my doc folder?

Note that this is a stand-alone document, not API documentation generated from the code.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [umlet-github](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umlet-github/paimimbkklhmfcbbgmhpfpjaikijhppl), a Google Chrome extension that allows you to create diagrams in [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/), store them as UXF files in your repository and view them in your browser within the GitHub interface.

[image: umlet-github converts UXF into SVG]

Answer (score 0):

I would say use Gliffy, where you can export diagrams to .JPG or .PDF and attach them to your README.md file.

You can also get a sharable link and include it in there. Very handy.